# Novel about entity that can move between objects

Tags: story-identification, novel

many years ago I read a book about an entity that moved into different objects, even people. In the beginning the entity moved into a tree and a person thought it was a magical tree as it spoke to them. Then it moved on into a person, and so on throughout the book. It was a very long time ago I read this novel and so the details are very sketchy. If anyone can help me find this book title again I would very much appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about this book? For example, when did you read it? Can you recall any plot details?

Comment: Was it a horror? Something designed for teenagers/kids?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it could be [Ghostwritten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostwritten), by David Mitchell. It's a series of short stories that are at first apparently unconnected but as they progress it is revealed that there is a non-corporeal entity passing from host to host through the characters in each tale and influencing events. In one story this "spirit" leads a woman to believe that a tree by her home is speaking to her (but it is actually the spirit, who is using her as a host).

Comment: Nathan, thank you so very much for taking the time to answer his for me. It was so long ago I remember very little of the story now. I think this may be the book. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to mark as the answer if it turns out to be correct!